# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ni > 0 && ni == ni1)

Tags: opencv

I have the following problem: Everything works fine, but when i reach the calibrateCamera Part i get the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ni > 0 && ni == ni1) in unknown function, file .
>   .....\src\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp, line 3197

I am new here, and maybe my code isn't as clear as it could be, but please be friendly.
Thank you very much in advance.

My code is: (i deleted the include and pragma parts, because it got really big letters here)

```
int _tmain()
{


printf("Everything loaded. Press Enter to continue.\n\a");


getch();

system("cls");                              //bildschirm clearen


int numBoards = 0;
int numCornersHor;
int numCornersVer;
char stCurPath[200];
int numFiles = 0;
char stRemFileNum[200];

int curNum;

vector<string> file_names;
string s;
bool pathok = false;

#pragma region ask user for path to load images and list them

//                                                  ask user for path to load images and list them                      




while(pathok == false)
{
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter path to the folder where the pictures are:\n");
scanf("%199[^\n]s", stCurPath);  //achtung wegen bufferoverflow - nicht mehr als 199 zeichen + EOF (0) einlesen.
                                 //[^\n] wegen Leerzeichen. scanf liest bis Enter.
system("cls");

DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
dir = opendir (stCurPath);




if (dir != NULL) {
/* print all the files and directories within directory */
    printf("Your chosen path:\n%s\n\nFiletree of this path:\n", stCurPath);
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
    {
        numFiles++; //Anzahl der Files
        printf ("%d)\t%s\n",numFiles, ent->d_name);
        s = ent->d_name;
        file_names.push_back(s);
    }
    closedir (dir);

    fflush( stdout );
    printf ("\nNumber of found files: %d\n", numFiles);

    pathok = true;
} 
else
{
    /* could not open directory */

    printf ("Could not open directory. Make sure path is ok!\n\n");
    pathok = false;

    /*perror ("");
    return EXIT_FAILURE*/;
}
}//while(pathok == false)
/*****************************end ask user for path to load images and list them****************************************/

#pragma endregion

#pragma region ask user to exclude some files

/*****************************************ask user to exclude some files*************************/
printf ("\nEnter the number of the files you dont want to load (number only!).\nSeperate single files with comma.\nEnter 0 if you don't want to exclude files.\nEnter x to exclude all non bmp files.\n\nNumbers:\n");
scanf("%199s", stRemFileNum);       //achtung wegen bufferoverflow - nicht mehr als 199 zeichen + EOF (0) einlesen
vector<string>::iterator it; 
if(strcmp(stRemFileNum,"x") == 0)
{
    curNum=1;
    numFiles = 0;
    string extstr;
    const char * extc;

    file_names.erase(remove_if(file_names.begin(),
                               file_names.end(),
                               isBmpExtension), file_names.end());

    system("cls");                      //bildschirm clearen
    printf("New Filetree of this path:\n\n");
    it = file_names.begin();
    for(it; it != file_names.end(); ++it)
    {
        numFiles++;
        printf ("%d)\t%s\n",numFiles, (*it).c_str());           
    }

    printf ("\nNumber of found files: %d\n", numFiles);
}//if(strcmp(stRemFileNum,"x") == 0)


//end user entered x

//start user entered 0

if(strcmp(stRemFileNum,"0") != 0 && strcmp(stRemFileNum,"x") != 0)
{

    //fehler
    numFiles = 0;
    vector<string> numbersVector;
    string strNumbers = stRemFileNum;
    Tokenize(strNumbers, numbersVector, ",");
    sort(numbersVector.begin(), numbersVector.end(), strCompDesc);

    for(it = numbersVector.begin(); it != numbersVector.end(); ++it)
    {
        curNum = atoi((*it).c_str());
        file_names.erase(file_names.begin() + (curNum - 1));
    }


    system("cls");                      //bildschirm clearen
    printf("New Filetree of this path:\n\n");

    //fehler ende

    for(vector<string>::iterator it = file_names.begin(); it != file_names.end(); ++it)
    {
        numFiles++;
        printf ("%d)\t%s\n",numFiles, (*it).c_str());           
    }

    printf ("\nNumber of found files: %d\n", numFiles);

}
//user entered 0
else if(strcmp(stRemFileNum,"0") == 0)
{
    printf ("\nNo files excluded.\n");
}


/*****************end ask user to exclude some files *******************************************/

#pragma endregion

fflush(stdin);
printf("\nEnter number of corners along width: ");
scanf("%d", &numCornersHor);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter number of corners along height: ");
scanf("%d", &numCornersVer);





int numSquares = numCornersHor * numCornersVer;
Size board_sz = Size(numCornersHor, numCornersVer);

vector<vector<Point3f>> object_points;
vector<vector<Point2f>> image_points;

vector<Point2f> corners;
vector<Point3f> obj;

int pictures_done=0;

Mat image;
Mat gray_image;


//Bilder zum persönlichen auswerten anzeigen +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

//

for(vector<string>::iterator it = file_names.begin(); it != file_names.end(); ++it)
{



printf("\nLoading Picture..\n");

image = imread(string(stCurPath) + "\\" + (*it).c_str()); //als farbe lesen; doppelter backslash o. normaler

//resize(image, image, Size(0,0), 0.5, 0.5, INTER_AREA);

cvtColor(image,gray_image,CV_RGB2GRAY);





for(int j=0;j<numSquares;j++)
{
    obj.push_back(Point3f(j/numCornersHor, j%numCornersHor, 0.0f));
}//for(int j=0;j<numSquares;j++)



bool found = findChessboardCorners(image, board_sz, corners, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

    if(found)
    {
        cornerSubPix(gray_image, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
        drawChessboardCorners(gray_image, board_sz, corners, found);
    }

    cvNamedWindow("win1", 1);
    imshow("win1", gray_image);
    waitKey(30);
    cvMoveWindow("win1",0,0);
    waitKey(30);
    printf("\nPicture loaded.\nPress a to load original, s to store snap and show next picture,");
    printf("\nd to drop snap and show next picture, and f to close the programm\n");

    char key; 
    bool bOriginalDisplayed = false;

    while(1)
    {
        if (cin.rdbuf()->in_avail())
        {
            key = _getch();
        }

        if('a' == key && found!=0)
        {
            if (!bOriginalDisplayed)
            {
                printf("\nLoading original..\n");
                cvNamedWindow("win2", 1);
                cvMoveWindow("win2",0,0);
                imshow("win2", image);                 //oder imshow cvMoveWindow("Smile", 100, 100); 

                bOriginalDisplayed = true;
                waitKey(50);
                printf("\nOriginal loaded.\nPess a again to close original before you continue.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                cvDestroyWindow("win2");
                printf("\nOriginal closed.\n");
                bOriginalDisplayed = false;
            }
        }

        if('s'==key)
        {
            image_points.push_back(corners);
            object_points.push_back(obj);
            printf("\nSnap stored!\n"); 
            pictures_done++;
            found = false;
            break;
        }

        if('d' == key)
        {
            pictures_done++;
            break;
            found = false;
        }

        if('f' == key)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        Sleep(50);
    } //while (1)



} //for(vector<string>::iterator it = file_names.begin(); it != file_names.end(); ++it)


cvDestroyWindow("win1");
waitKey(50);

Mat intrinsic = Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
Mat distCoeffs;
vector<Mat> rvecs;
vector<Mat> tvecs;


intrinsic.ptr<float>(0)[0] = 1;
intrinsic.ptr<float>(1)[1] = 1;

calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, image.size(), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);


Mat imageUndistorted;

for(vector<string>::iterator it = file_names.begin(); it != file_names.end(); ++it)
{
printf("\nLoading undistorted Picture..\n");
image = imread(string(stCurPath) + "\\" + (*it).c_str()); //als farbe lesen; doppelter backslash o. normaler    
//resize(image, image, Size(0,0), 0.5, 0.5, INTER_AREA);
cvtColor(image,gray_image,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    cvNamedWindow("win1", 1);
    cvNamedWindow("win2", 1);
    cvMoveWindow("win1",0,0);
    cvMoveWindow("win2",0,0);
    undistort(image, imageUndistorted, intrinsic, distCoeffs);
    imshow("win1", image);
    waitKey(0);
    imshow("win2", imageUndistorted);
    waitKey(30);
    printf("\nPicture loaded. Press s for the next picture or f to exit.");

    char key; 
    bool bOriginalDisplayed = false;

    while(1)
    {
        if (cin.rdbuf()->in_avail())
        {
            key = _getch();
        }

        if('s'==key)
        {
            break;
        }

        if('f' == key)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        Sleep(50);
    } //while (1)



} //for(vector<string>::iterator it = file_names.begin(); it != file_names.end(); ++it)








return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you post code, be sure to indent it by four spaces so that it's recognized as code. Also, you should pare your example code down to the minimum necessary to reproduce your problem. That will make it a lot easier, and thus more likely, for someone to give you help. There's a lot of extraneous code in here for us to wade through.

Comment: I found the answer, if you are interested, look below in my question.

Comment: you should accept your own solution when you found and posted it. In addition to wath SSteve said, I would also suggest that *if* you leave comments in the code, let them be comments useful and helpful to people trying to help you. The comments in German just make it harder for us to read it and to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If found the problem. And me being a good person i came here to post the answer for people having the same issue in the future.

Solution: Add a obj.clear() into the for function so obj always stays same size when you push back. Like this:

```
    //Bilder zum persönlichen auswerten anzeigen +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//

for(vector<string>::iterator it = file_names.begin(); it != file_names.end(); ++it)
{
    printf("\nLoading Picture..\n");
    image = imread(string(stCurPath) + "\\" + (*it).c_str()); //als farbe lesen; doppelter backslash o. normaler
    //resize(image, image, Size(0,0), 0.5, 0.5, INTER_AREA);
    cvtColor(image,gray_image,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    obj.clear();
    for(int j=0;j<numSquares;j++)
    {
        obj.push_back(Point3f(j/numCornersHor, j%numCornersHor, 0.0f));
    }//for(int j=0;j<numSquares;j++)

    bool found = findChessboardCorners(image, board_sz, corners, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

    if(found)
```

Have fun programming. Greets, Escore.

Comment: this dies not fix the problem for me .