# OpencCV error during calibration

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, calibration

This is my calibratio code:

```
   void calibrate()
 {
    int numBoards = 21;
    int board_w = 6;
    int board_h = 9;
    Size board_sz = Size(board_w, board_h);
    int board_n = board_w*board_h;
    vector<vector<Point3f> > object_points;
    vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints1, imagePoints2;
    vector<Point2f> corners1, corners2;
    vector<Point3f> obj;
    for (int j=0; j<board_n; j++)
    {
        obj.push_back(Point3f(j/board_w, j%board_w, 0.0f));
    }
    Mat img1, img2, gray1, gray2;
    VideoCapture cap1(0);// = VideoCapture(0);
    VideoCapture cap2(1);// = VideoCapture(1);
    int success = 0, k = 0;
    bool found1 = false, found2 = false;
    namedWindow("left 1");
    namedWindow("right 1");
    while (success < numBoards)
    {
        cap1 >> img1;
        cap2 >> img2;
        //resize(img1, img1, Size(320, 280));
        //resize(img2, img2, Size(320, 280));
        //waitKey(0);
        cvtColor(img1, gray1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvtColor(img2, gray2, CV_BGR2GRAY);


        found1 = findChessboardCorners(img1, board_sz, corners1, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);
        found2 = findChessboardCorners(img2, board_sz, corners2, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);
        if (found1)
        {
            cornerSubPix(gray1, corners1, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
            drawChessboardCorners(gray1, board_sz, corners1, found1);
        }
        if (found2)
        {
            cornerSubPix(gray2, corners2, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
            drawChessboardCorners(gray2, board_sz, corners2, found2);
        }
        imshow("left 1", img1);
        imshow("right 1", img2);
        k = waitKey(2);

        if(found1 && found2) cout<<"succeeded: "<<success<<endl;

        if ( found1  && found2)
        {
            imagePoints1.push_back(corners1);
            imagePoints2.push_back(corners2);
            object_points.push_back(obj);
            printf ("Corners stored\n");
            cout<<"Obj points size: "<<object_points.size()<<endl;
            cout<<"Image1 points size: "<<imagePoints1.size()<<endl;
            cout<<"Image2 points size: "<<imagePoints2.size()<<endl;
            success++;
            if (success >= numBoards)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    destroyAllWindows();
    printf("Starting Calibration\n");
    Mat CM1 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
    Mat CM2 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
    Mat D1, D2;
    Mat R, T, E, F;
    double calibErr = stereoCalibrate(object_points, imagePoints1, imagePoints2,
    CM1, D1, CM2, D2, img1.size(), R, T, E, F,
    cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),
    CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH | CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST);
    FileStorage fs1("mystereocalib.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs1 << "CM1" << CM1;
    fs1 << "CM2" << CM2;
    fs1 << "D1" << D1;
    fs1 << "D2" << D2;
    fs1 << "R" << R;
    fs1 << "T" << T;
    fs1 << "E" << E;
    fs1 << "F" << F;
    fs1<<"Error"<<calibErr;
    printf("Done Calibration\n");
    printf("Calibration error: %f\n", calibErr);
    printf("Starting Rectification\n");
    Mat R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
    stereoRectify(CM1, D1, CM2, D2, img1.size(), R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q);
    fs1 << "R1" << R1;
    fs1 << "R2" << R2;
    fs1 << "P1" << P1;
    fs1 << "P2" << P2;
    fs1 << "Q" << Q;
    printf("Done Rectification\n");
    printf("Applying Undistort\n");
    Mat map1x, map1y, map2x, map2y;
    Mat imgU1, imgU2;
    initUndistortRectifyMap(CM1, D1, R1, P1, img1.size(), CV_32FC1, map1x, map1y);
    initUndistortRectifyMap(CM2, D2, R2, P2, img2.size(), CV_32FC1, map2x, map2y);
    printf("Undistort complete\n");

    cap1.release();
    cap2.release();
    return;
 }
```

I got this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ni >= 0) in
>   cv::collectCalibrationData, file ..\
>   ......\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp, line 3169

I ran this code on other computer and it works fine. What is wrong?

Comment: Have you already checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723656/opencv-error-assertion-failed-ni-0-ni-ni1) out?

Comment: Which line in your code? `double calibErr = stereoCalibrate(...)`?

Comment: @yildirim: Yes I checked that. But I don't have such problem my object_points and image_points have the same size I checked.

Comment: @Kornel: Yes, this line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that I use openCV dll files from vc10 folder using vs2012 when I change to vc11 it works.